# bi-directional conditional type mapping

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I'm mapping the "data types" of an object to a "schema" type.

> When property data type == boolean, map to "BooleanComponents" type

The following code accomplish this:

```
type YesNoComponent = {
    type: 'yes-no'
}

type CheckboxComponent = {
    type: 'checkbox'
}

type TextComponent = {
    type: 'text'
}

type BooleanComponents = YesNoComponent | CheckboxComponent;
type StringComponents = TextComponent;

// this maps the Schema Data "type" to a "line type"
type TypeToComponent<T> = T extends string ? StringComponents :
    T extends boolean ? BooleanComponents :
    unknown;

type DataTypeToComponentSchema<T> = {
    [key in keyof T] : TypeToComponent<T[key]>
}

type FooDataType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}

type FooComponentType = DataTypeToComponentSchema<FooDataType>

//  type ComponentType = {
//    foo: StringComponents;
//    bar: BooleanComponents;
//  }
```

[ts-playgroud link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=10&pln=41&pc=1#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-Ke3bIJ2QEnnS6WG6RAOPWEQlWPH5qf65wGRXzR0KxiIQ3VgsvUJEo5DozESvwABWKyEgxVAGegJFTePTkxlGkOqT0GXrwBd7RLlSAA)

However, I also need to map "Component Types" back to the "Data Types".

I could do the same thing as before, just inverse:

```
type ComponentTypeToDataType<T> = T extends StringComponents ? string:
    T extends BooleanComponents ? boolean:
    unknown;

type FooPropertyDataType = ComponentTypeToDataType<CheckboxComponent>
// boolean
```

But this is less than ideal to maintain.

I'm wondering if there is some method or trick to define a single "relationship" between the two type sets which would support bi-directional mappings?

Comment: I just tested using "tuple types" can be used to at least pair them together... still feels like there might be a better way to manage this tho.  

Maybe `ts-toolbelt` has something that can help clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [a type "Switch" statement](https://www.peterstuart.org/posts/2020-03-07-writing-type-level-switch-statement-typescript/) and adding an "Inverse Switch" to reverse the mapping:

```
type SwitchInverse<T, Conditions extends Array<[any, any]>> = 
      List.Head<Conditions> extends never
        ? never
        : T extends List.Head<Conditions>[1]
          ? List.Head<Conditions>[0]
          : SwitchInverse<T, List.Tail<Conditions>>;
```

The I can manage all the mappings in one place:

```
type TypeComponentMappings<S> = [
    [boolean, YesNoComponent | CheckboxComponent],
    [string, TextComponent | SelectComponent],
    //...
];
export type AllComponents<S> = TypeComponentMappings<S>[number][1];
```

This uses "recursive types", so we'll see how well it holds up.

Still think there could be a "cleaner way" to do this...